Poisson distribution occurring in the analytic continuation of the Bernoulli Numbers?
I derived an analytic continuation of the Bernoulli Numbers as $$B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(k)}{\Gamma(n-x+1)}(-k)^{n-x}$$ Where $$f^{(n)}(x):=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$ Which works consistently for integers $\ge0$, but when $k$ is changed every other value changes. That is an interesting problem, but I'm going to ignore it for now; what I find way more interesting is that $B(x)$, when graphed, strongly resembles a Poisson Distribution reflected across the y-axis. Why is this?

What is $k$ in your formula? What does both graph looks like?

k is a defined point on the function, as found in Taylor Series that cannot be evaluated at 0. The graph resembles $-s\zeta(1-s)$, but the values are slightly off, both too high and too low.

You should edit that in. And $-s\zeta(1-s)$ is the generalization of the bernoulli numbers to the reals.

@Nolord But what does that have to do with the Poisson Distribution?

I don't see any connection, not even on the graph... That's why I asked you to edit in the graph.
